# How do I replace corrupted /etc/inittab and /etc/init.d/rcS files?

Tags: 11.10, default, init, init.d

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop and I have managed to overwrite my /etc/inittab and /etc/init.d/rcS files while running a stupid script with sudo.

Can anyone please provide me the default installed /etc/inittab and /etc/init.d/rcS files on a ubuntu 11.10 system so that I can restore it back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ ls -l /etc/inittab
ls: cannot access /etc/inittab: No such file or directory
```

So there is no inittab in my installation.

```
$ ls -l /etc/init.d/rcS 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 117 2011-07-14 07:11 /etc/init.d/rcS

$ cat /etc/init.d/rcS 
#! /bin/sh
#
# rcS
#
# Call all S??* scripts in /etc/rcS.d/ in numerical/alphabetical order
#

exec /etc/init.d/rc S
```

Comment: I'm glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Intall a live CD
2. $sudo fdisk -l #Check which partition your Ubuntu is.
3. $sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt # ex. My Ubuntu is on /dev/sda1
4. $sudo chroot /mnt
5. #cd /mnt/etc/init.d
6. Now you can edit rcS or replace it
7. #exit
8. $sudo umount /mnt/
9. sudo reboot